# Java text editor/parsing framework

Tags: java, parsing, scala, text-editor, lexer

First a little introduction to my situation:
I have just started a hobby project, in regard to building my own TextEditor, called BlazeEdit. I'm writing it in Scala, and have hence, choosen to work on the JVM. 
I am planning to a lot of things differently than how it was done in jEdit. For instance using Actors all the way around, and also trying to defeat, "in-my-world" a slow start for the jEdit editor.

However regarding the development of an Text Editor window, which should be able to do things like, syntax highlighting, formatting etc. I would not like to begin from scrath, since this is a very big task.

So my question is, if there are some good Java, Scala etc. frameworks that I could use, which are not to heavy like for instance the Eclipse framework.

If you need more details please say so.

Thanks in advance.

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) is an excellent such framework, but works on top of some Eclipse plugins. Given an EBNF-like description of a language, it generates a model, a parser, an editor with syntax highlighting, auto-completion, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a framework, but    [SlateIDE](https://github.com/asinghal/SlateIDE) is an editor written in scala, you may find something useful there.